# Count how many times a given combination occurs in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list called `huge_list`, as the name says it is pretty large. I need to know how I can get how many times a given combination of 2 elements of the sublists occur, for example:

```
huge_list = [[6,10,5,4,40,99],[1,10,3,6,40,71],[2,10,3,4,40,98]]

count = 0
for x in huge_list:
    #print amount of times position 1 and 4 have the same combination
    count = count + 1
```

and the output would be:

```
3
3
3
```

I tried something like :

```
sum(x.count(huge_list[count][1]) for x in huge_list)
```

But it works for just one of the items, not both of them. Any ideas?

Comment: are you only need position 1 and 4 ? or for all of them ?

Comment: Do you want the number of lists that have the same content for a pair of given positions? Or the number of times a given number appears in each list? Or something else?

Comment: Just 1 and 4, I'm changing the example a little to reflect that

Comment: What's the expected output for something like `[[0,1,10,30,2,83], [0,1, 93, 82, 2, 1], [0,1, 93, 82, 3, 3], [0,1, 93, 82, 3, 1]]`? Are we literally just looking that indexes `1` and `4` are a certain couple of numbers?

Comment: @AdamSmith the output for that would be 1, 2, 1, 2

Comment: So, you want to specify indexes `1` and `4`, then specify values `10 ` and `40`, then check how many lists have a `10` at index `1` and a `40` at index `4`?

Comment: @rodrigocf Okay then I'm very confused. You need to do a better job of explaining why that output is `1 2 1 2`

Comment: @rodrigocf does your sublists  has the same length?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a count of all the combinations of indexes `1` and `4` in a list of lists, it's hard to do better than:

```
import collections

huge_list = [[6,10,5,4,40,99],[1,10,3,6,40,71],[2,10,3,4,40,98]]
count = collections.Counter(((sublst[1], sublst[4]) for sublst in huge_list))
```

Which will give you:

```
In [3]: count
Out[3]: Counter({(10,40): 3})
```

You can get your exact requested output after this with:

```
for sublst in huge_list:
    print(count.get((sublst[1], sublst[4]), 0))
```

Comment: You can use a generator expression, you don't need to build the list first

Comment: @Kasra are you sure? It's unclear to me if OP only wants the most common element.

Comment: If the OP is not checking for repeated particular elements I think `print(sum(v > 1 for v in count.values()))` is maybe what they want which will count how many times there are at least two repeated occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

If you are given two numbers to check you can sum :

```
huge_list = [[6,10,5,4,40,99],[1,10,3,6,40,71],[2,10,3,4,40,98]]

given = (10, 40)
print(sum((sub[1], sub[4]) == given for sub in huge_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried for your expected output.I dont know what you are expecting actually

```
huge_list = [[6,10,5,4,40,99],[1,10,3,6,40,71],[2,10,3,4,40,98]]
for i in huge_list:
    c = 0
    for j in huge_list:
        if i[1]==j[1] and i[4]==j[4]:
            c+=1
    print c

#output
3
3
3
```